# How to ignore 'java.io.serialization' logger in java

Tags: java

To adress security vulnerability CVE-2017-3241 (Java RMI Registry.bind() Unvalidated Deserialization) which affects JRE version prior to 1.8.0_121. In addition to using JRE 1.8.0_121 ,we added below lines of code in java.security file.

```
jdk.serialFilter=*
sun.rmi.registry.registryFilter=*

sun.rmi.transport.dgcFilter=\
    java.rmi.server.ObjID;\
    java.rmi.server.UID;\
    java.rmi.dgc.VMID;\
    java.rmi.dgc.Lease;\          maxdepth=2147483647;maxarray=2147483647;maxrefs=2147483647;maxbytes=2147483647
```

Once we add these lines then we are getting below lines whenever do any RMI call.

```
Feb 13, 2017 1:00:53 AM sun.misc.ObjectInputFilter$Config lambda$static$0
INFO: Creating serialization filter from *
```

We want to suppress these info, can somebody suggest any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I use -Djdk.serialFilter=maxbytes=10000;!org.* as JVM arguments, don`t see any log info.